# javascript date problem

Tags: javascript

my problem datetime now Add 63 day.

javascript code:

```
var aDate = new Date();
var ax_year = aDate.getFullYear();
var ax_mon = aDate.getDate();
var ax_day = aDate.getDay();
var axDate = ax_mon + '.' + ax_day + '.' + ax_year;
```

axDate = now 28.05.2010

i need axDate + 63 day = 31.07.2010 how to make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add 63 days to aDate

```
aDate.setDate(aDate.getDate() + 63);
```

Comment: Well, that's what I get for wanting to bee too fast. This is the correct solution. +1, and time for me to start the weekend :)

Comment: most likely he made axdate=johns expression, which changes the date object but returns an integer in an assignment.